# How to calculate initial and final temperatures during supercritical steam expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

> Ten $\mathrm{kg}$ of steam at $500~\mathrm{bar}$ is expanded at constant pressure until its volume increases to seven times its initial value of $0.01~\mathrm{m^3}$.
>   (a) Calculate the initial and final temperature of the steam
>   (b) Calculate the heat that must be supplied to carry out the process

An attempt at solving this problem:
$$\Delta H + \Delta E_k + \Delta E_p = Q - W_S\ \ \text{(open system)}$$

Taking out unnecessary terms leaves us with
\begin{aligned}
\Delta H &= Q\\ 
500~\mathrm{bar} &= 5\cdot10^7~\mathrm{Pa}\\
\Delta H &= H_f - H_i\\
H_i &= (5\cdot10^7~\mathrm{Pa})\cdot(0.01~\mathrm{m^3}) = 5\cdot10^5~\mathrm{J}\\
H_f &= (5\cdot10^7~\mathrm{Pa})\cdot(0.07~\mathrm{m^3}) = 3.5\cdot10^6~\mathrm{J}\\
\end{aligned}

Converting to kJ/kg (10 kg of steam)
\begin{aligned}
\hat{H}_i &= 50~\mathrm{kJ/kg}\\
\hat{H}_f &= 350~\mathrm{kJ/kg}\\
\end{aligned}

And that's where I stopped. I tried looking up the values of $\hat{H}_i$ and $\hat{H}_f$ in steam tables to interpolate the temperatures, but the values are too low. Since the pressure is too high, I also know the ideal gas law $(PV=nRT)$ won't apply to this scenario. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Since supercritical steam is not an ideal gas, you might want to use standard reference data (e.g. provided by NIST).

**Initial state**
mass *m*<sub>0</sub> = 10 kg
pressure *p*<sub>0</sub> = 500 bar = 50.0 MPa
volume *V*<sub>0</sub> = 0.01 m<sup>3</sup>
density *ρ*<sub>0</sub> = 1000 kg/m<sup>3</sup>
temperature *T*<sub>0</sub> = 340.53 K
specific enthalpy *h*<sub>0</sub> = 323.06 kJ/kg

**Final state**
mass *m*<sub>1</sub> = 10 kg
pressure *p*<sub>1</sub> = 500 bar = 50.0 MPa
volume *V*<sub>1</sub> = 0.07 m<sup>3</sup>
density *ρ*<sub>1</sub> = 142.86 kg/m<sup>3</sup>
temperature *T*<sub>1</sub> = 925.86 K
specific enthalpy *h*<sub>1</sub> = 3453.11 kJ/kg

**Heat transfer**
heat *Q* = Δ*H* = (*h*<sub>1</sub> – *h*<sub>0</sub>) • *m* = 31.3 MJ

Comment: Hi @Loong. Generally with answers to questions such as this, it's preferred that you show the processes of *how* to arrive at the answer.

Comment: With standard reference data, you simply look up the data. There is no process, except for the last line of my answer.